# Editing cell of TableView on addition of row not working

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a table that I want to start editing the first column as soon as I click the + button to add a row.   The problem is, when I click the + button, it doesn't put the first row in edit mode, and if you press the + button again, it finally puts the first row into editing mode.  I also want it so that once I commit the value, it starts the editing of the next column.

Here are my classes:

Cheque.java

```
package tester;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;


public class Cheque
{

    private final SimpleStringProperty chequeNumber;
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> chequeAmount;
    private final ObservableValue changeProperty;

    public Cheque()
    {
        this.chequeNumber = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.chequeAmount = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        this.changeProperty = Bindings.concat(chequeNumber, chequeAmount);

    }

    public Cheque(String chequeNumber, BigDecimal amount)
    {
        this();
        this.chequeNumber.set(chequeNumber);
        this.chequeAmount.set(amount);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public ObservableValue getChangedProperty()
    {
        return this.changeProperty;
    }

    /**
     * @return the chequeNumber
     */
    public SimpleStringProperty getChequeNumberProperty()
    {
        return chequeNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return the chequeAmount
     */

    public SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> getChequeAmountProperty()
    {
        return chequeAmount;
    }

    public String getChequeNumber()
    {
        return chequeNumber.get();
    }

    public void setChequeNumber(String newValue)
    {
        this.chequeNumber.set(newValue);
    }

    public BigDecimal getChequeAmount()
    {
        return chequeAmount.get();
    }

    public void setChequeAmount(BigDecimal newValue)
    {
        this.chequeAmount.set(newValue);
    }



}
```

ChequeTable.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package tester;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class ChequeTable
{

    private final TableView<Cheque> table;
    private final ObservableList<Cheque> data;
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> chequeTotal;

    public ChequeTable()
    {

        this.table = new TableView<>();
        this.data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        this.chequeTotal = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        setUpTable();
    }



    public void clear()
    {
        this.data.clear();           
    }



    private void setUpTable()
    {

        this.table.setEditable(true);
        this.table.setItems(this.data);


        TableColumn<Cheque, String> numberCol = new TableColumn<Cheque, String>("Cheque #");
        numberCol.setCellFactory(column -> EditCell.createStringEditCell());
        numberCol.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().getChequeNumberProperty());
        numberCol.setMinWidth(100);

        TableColumn<Cheque, BigDecimal> chequeAmountCol = new TableColumn<Cheque, BigDecimal>("Total $");
        chequeAmountCol.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().getChequeAmountProperty());
        chequeAmountCol.setCellFactory(column -> EditCell.createMoneyEditCell());
        chequeAmountCol.setMinWidth(50);

        TableColumn<Cheque, Boolean> addCol = new TableColumn<Cheque, Boolean>();
        addCol.setGraphic(new Button("+"));
        addCol.setPrefWidth(45);
        addCol.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
        addCol.setSortable(false);
        Button addButton = (Button) addCol.getGraphic();
        addButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) ->
        {
            Cheque cheque = new Cheque("Cheque#", BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(2));

            data.add(cheque);
            table.scrollTo(cheque);
            table.requestFocus();
            table.getSelectionModel().select(cheque);
            table.edit(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), numberCol);

        });
        this.table.getColumns().addAll(numberCol, chequeAmountCol, addCol);

    }

    public TableView getTableView()
    {
        return this.table;
    }




}
```

Tester.java

```
package tester;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Tester extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {

        ChequeTable chequeTable = new ChequeTable();

        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(chequeTable.getTableView());

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

            launch(args);

    }

}
```

EditCell.java

```
package tester;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Objects;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class EditCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T>
{

    // Text field for editing
    // TODO: allow this to be a plugable control.
    private final TextField textField = new TextField();

    // Converter for converting the text in the text field to the user type, and vice-versa:
    private final StringConverter<T> converter;
    private final TextAlignment alignment;

    /**
     *
     * @param converter
     * @param alignment
     */
    public EditCell(StringConverter<T> converter, TextAlignment alignment)
    {

        this.converter = converter;
        this.alignment = alignment;
        this.textField.setAlignment(getPosition(alignment));
        itemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends T> obx, T oldItem, T newItem) ->
        {

            if (newItem == null)
            {
                setText(null);

            } else
            {
                setText(converter.toString(newItem));
            }

        });

        setGraphic(textField);

        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        setAlignment(getPosition(alignment));

        textField.setOnAction(evt ->
        {
            commitEdit(this.converter.fromString(textField.getText()));
        });

        textField.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs, Boolean wasFocused, Boolean isNowFocused) ->
        {

            if (!isNowFocused)
            {
                commitEdit(this.converter.fromString(textField.getText()));
            }

        });

        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (KeyEvent event) ->
        {

            if (null != event.getCode())
            {
                switch (event.getCode())
                {
                    case ESCAPE:
                        textField.setText(converter.toString(getItem()));
                        cancelEdit();
                        event.consume();
                        break;
                    case UP:
                        getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectAboveCell();
                        event.consume();
                        break;
                    case DOWN:
                        getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell();
                        event.consume();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        });

    }

    /**
     *
     * Convenience converter that does nothing (converts Strings to themselves
     * and vice-versa...).
     *
     */
    public static final StringConverter<String> IDENTITY_CONVERTER = new StringConverter<String>()
    {

        @Override
        public String toString(String object)
        {
            return object;
        }

        @Override
        public String fromString(String string)
        {
            return string;
        }

    };

    /**
     *
     */
    public static final StringConverter<BigDecimal> BIG_DECIMAL_MONEY_CONVERTER = new StringConverter<BigDecimal>()
    {
        @Override
        public String toString(BigDecimal object)
        {
            if (object == null)
            {
                return null;
            } else
            {
                return object.toPlainString();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal fromString(String string)
        {
            BigDecimal test = new BigDecimal(string);

            test = test.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

            return test;
        }
    };

    /**
     *
     * Convenience method for creating an EditCell for a String value.
     *
     * @param <S>
     * @return
     *
     */
    public static <S> EditCell<S, String> createStringEditCell()
    {
        return new EditCell<>(IDENTITY_CONVERTER, TextAlignment.LEFT);

    }

    /**
     *
     * @param <S>
     * @return
     */
    public static <S> EditCell<S, BigDecimal> createMoneyEditCell()
    {
        return new EditCell<>(BIG_DECIMAL_MONEY_CONVERTER, TextAlignment.RIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        TableColumn tableCol = (TableColumn) getTableColumn();
        if (item != null && tableCol.getWidth() < new Text(item + "  ").getLayoutBounds().getWidth())
        {
            tooltipProperty().bind(Bindings.when(Bindings.or(emptyProperty(), itemProperty().isNull())).then((Tooltip) null).otherwise(new Tooltip(item.toString())));
        } else
        {
            tooltipProperty().bind(Bindings.when(Bindings.or(emptyProperty(), itemProperty().isNull())).then((Tooltip) null).otherwise((Tooltip) null));
        }
    }

    // set the text of the text field and display the graphic
    @Override
    public void startEdit()
    {

        super.startEdit();
        textField.setText(converter.toString(getItem()));
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        textField.requestFocus();

    }

    // revert to text display
    @Override
    public void cancelEdit()
    {

        super.cancelEdit();
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        setAlignment(getPosition(alignment));
    }

    // commits the edit. Update property if possible and revert to text display
    @Override
    public void commitEdit(T item)
    {

        // This block is necessary to support commit on losing focus, because the baked-in mechanism
        // sets our editing state to false before we can intercept the loss of focus.
        // The default commitEdit(...) method simply bails if we are not editing...
        if (!isEditing() && !Objects.equals(item, getItem()))
        {

            TableView<S> table = getTableView();

            if (table != null)
            {

                TableColumn<S, T> column = getTableColumn();
                CellEditEvent<S, T> event = new CellEditEvent<>(table,
                        new TablePosition<>(table, getIndex(), column),
                        TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), item);
                Event.fireEvent(column, event);

            }

        }

        super.commitEdit(item);

        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        setAlignment(getPosition(alignment));
    }

    private static Pos getPosition(TextAlignment textAlignment)
    {

        switch (textAlignment)
        {
            case CENTER:
                return Pos.CENTER;
            case RIGHT:
                return Pos.CENTER_RIGHT;
            case LEFT:
                return Pos.CENTER_LEFT;
            default:
                return Pos.CENTER_LEFT;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please stick to the _M_ in [MCVE] :) not willing to wade through so much unrelated code, just a side comment (not directly related): if you need to call refresh after modifying the table's items normally, then there's something severely wrong in your setup!

Comment: I didn't need to call refresh, I just thought I should. I removed a bunch of unrelated code.

Comment: still too much but much better :) I see the point now: table has a problem (maybe a bug) with adding an item and starting an edit on the newly added item - when calling table.edit(...) the internal state is not yet fully updated. And that .. ta-taaa ... is (nearly) the only context where forcing such an update via refresh is acceptable (as long as the bug isn't fixed): so so after select(..) and before edit(..). And in your cell impl, wrap textField.requestFocus into Platform.runlater to really grab the the focus. With those two changes it seems to work (fx11), though feels a bit sluggish

Comment: Hmm... ok, so put a Platform.runlater request focus in here? public void startEdit()  Where do I add the textfield request focus after select? I don't have access to the textfield from there (only the table).